# How to test invalid url by cy.request in Cypress

Tags: cypress

```
it('status', () => {
  cy.request('https://tilesea.c/')
    .then((resp) => {
      if (resp.status === 0) {
  
        // cy.log('Failed to load URL');
        // cy.writeFile('l       ogs/failed.log', 'failed')
      }
    })

})
```

I want to verify link by their status code and i am using cy.request in cypress but did not work.
Got error - Error in loading page , Network error, how to handle this error

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the configuration `failOnStatusCode`:

```
  return cy.request<R>({
    method: "GET",
    url: url,
    failOnStatusCode: false, // this is required
    qs: queries,
    headers: {
      accept: "application/json",
    },
  });
```

OR for a website

```
return cy.visit({
  url: url,
  failOnStatusCode: false, // this is required
}
```

Comment: I tried this also, but not working for me 

I got this error:

cy.request() failed trying to load:



https://tilesea.c/



We attempted to make an http request to this URL but the request failed without a response.



We received this error at the network level:



  > Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND tilesea.c



-----------------------------------------------------------



The request we sent was:



Method: GET

URL: https://tilesea.c/

Comment: Is it an API or a website your are fetching?

Comment: I have updated the answer if it's a website you are trying to get.